# Dictionary as key of another Dictionary / count number of equal Dictionarys

Tags: c#, dictionary, histogram

I want to use a Dictionary as the key of another Dictionary, but the comparision for equal keys shall not use the reference for comparision, but the Dictionary's content. How can I do this?

Here is what I currently have: I want to know how many equal histograms (implemented as Dictionary) I have. For that I create another Dictionary `numberOfHistogramOccurences` with the histograms as key, the value shall then be increased by one on each new addition of a histogram with equal content.

I am also open for hints on other ways of counting content-equal histograms/Dictionaries.

```
// define two histograms with equal content
Dictionary<int, int>[] histograms = new Dictionary<int, int>[2];

histograms[0] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
histograms[0][0] = 3;
histograms[0][5] = 1;
histograms[0][10] = 8;

histograms[1] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
histograms[1][0] = 3;
histograms[1][5] = 1;
histograms[1][10] = 8;


// use the equal histograms as key.
// as they are reference types, their reference is compared and not their content ):
var numberOfHistogramOccurences = new Dictionary<Dictionary<int, int>, int>();

foreach (var histogram in histograms)
{
    if (!numberOfHistogramOccurences.ContainsKey(histogram))
        numberOfHistogramOccurences[histogram] = 0;

    numberOfHistogramOccurences[histogram]++;
}

// this gives two different keys;
// I need one key with a value of 2,
// as both histograms are equal
Debug.WriteLine("Number of different keys in numberOfHistogramOccurences: " + numberOfHistogramOccurences.Keys.Count);
```

Comment: You can set the `comparer` when initializing your `Dictionary`. You could write your own method two check _key-dictionary_ equality.

Comment: Note, that `GetHashCode` might be called quite a lot. So if your idea is to go through all entries of the dictionary and use some math on them to get a useful hash, this might slow down your application if there are a lot of entries. Maybe you don't want to use a `Dictionary` directly, but some `Histogram` class that *uses* a `Dictionary` internally. Probably a `ReadOnlyDictionary`, since the values shouldn't change when you use them as keys. Then you could generate the hash once and store it. `Equals` should still be done thoroughly, but that's only called on equal hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, using a custom `comparer`. Note that I added another histogram in order to check that it sees differences as well.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // define two histograms with equal content
    Dictionary<int, int>[] histograms = new Dictionary<int, int>[2];

    histograms[0] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    histograms[0][0] = 3;
    histograms[0][5] = 1;
    histograms[0][10] = 8;

    histograms[1] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    histograms[1][0] = 3;
    histograms[1][5] = 1;
    histograms[1][10] = 8;

    histograms[2] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    histograms[2][0] = 1;
    histograms[2][5] = 3;
    histograms[2][10] = 8;


    // use the equal histograms as key.
    // as they are reference types, their reference is compared and not their content ):

    /* change this line */
    var numberOfHistogramOccurences = new Dictionary<Dictionary<int, int>, int>(new HistogramComparer());
    /* ---------------- */

    foreach (var histogram in histograms)
    {
        if (!numberOfHistogramOccurences.ContainsKey(histogram))
            numberOfHistogramOccurences[histogram] = 0;

        numberOfHistogramOccurences[histogram]++;
    }

    // this gives two different keys;
    // I need one key with a value of 2,
    // as both histograms are equal
    Debug.WriteLine("Number of different keys in numberOfHistogramOccurences: " + numberOfHistogramOccurences.Keys.Count);
}
```

And the custom comparer class `HistogramComparer`:

```
public class HistogramComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<int, int>>
{
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<int, int> x, Dictionary<int, int> y)
    {
        // check that y contains all x.Keys
        foreach (var key in x.Keys)
            if (!y.Keys.Contains(key))
                return false;
        // check that x contains all y.Keys
        foreach (var key in y.Keys)
            if (!x.Keys.Contains(key))
                return false;

        // check that keys have same values
        foreach (var entry in x)
            if (y[entry.Key] != entry.Value)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<int, int> obj)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (var entry in obj)
            hash ^= (entry.Key ^ entry.Value);

        return hash;
    }
}
```